# ASP.NET AJAX Library

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Coolite facilitates DialogBox, Window, form, etc. (i.e. most of the controls similar to Desktop GUIs). Is there any other library like 'Coolite Toolkit' for ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free or fee?  [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) and [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/) both have extensive control libraries for ASP.NET that include both server-side and client-side components.  Most, if not all, of these controls would work with ASP.NET AJAX.  Microsoft hosts a [community control gallery](http://www.asp.net/Community/Control-gallery/) with many more on their [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net) site.

Answer (score 1):

Free use;

there is BackBase Ajax Framework built in Java but can be used through script blocks.

http://bdn.backbase.com/client

and theres WEB UI of ComponentArt,looks nice :) at componentartdotcom